# Are there any Erlang-ready continuous integration systems available?

Tags: erlang, continuous-integration

I'd like to start using [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) in my personal projects to get experience with the techniques and concepts.  The problem is that my programming poison runs to the non-mainstream (to put it mildly) with the bulk of my work being in Erlang.

What continuous integration systems are capable of dealing with non-mainstream languages, chief among them, in my case, Erlang?  How easy are they to set up, configure and run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point I'd recommend [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29). It is easy to setup and configure, there are lots of help online and basic support with the common Erlang test tools.

See Stack Overflow question *[Continuous integration server for Erlang code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215166)* for basic information about how to intergrate eunit and common test into Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Jenkins-CI in the etorrent project and that seem to work really well. We have a number of virtual machines implementing different operating systems on which we run the system and then carry out tests.